# For Loop coming up short

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am making a multiplication table that takes input from the user and builds an n by n table.  However with that script that I have, it always is displaying one less row and column than intended.  What am I missing here?

JS:

```
function happy(rows, cols){
        var hcode = '';
        w=window.open();
        //w.document.write("here are " + rows + cols)
        w.document.write("<table border='1'><tr> </td>");
        for (j=1; j<cols; j++){
            w.document.write("<tr>");
            w.document.write("<td bgcolor='plum'>"+ j +"</td>");    
            //w.document.write("<tr>");

            for (i=2; i<rows; i++){
                    w.document.write("<td>" + j*i + "</td>");
            }
            w.document.write("</tr>")
        }
        w.document.write("</table>");       
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you be using rows for the outer loop and cols for the inner loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error if you're surprised by the results. If you weren't surprised by the results then it's by design.

You can try this out yourself, on paper.

Say you want to count to 3, and you start at 1.

- So the first number is 1, increment by 1
- Check if the number is less than 3, yes it is, the second number is 2, increment by 1
- Check if the number is less than 3, no it isn't (3 is not less than 3)

There is no third number. Because you've stopped the loop with the check `number<3`.

To get around this check if the number is less than or equals to 3 instead:

```
for (j=1; j<=cols; j++){ ...
```

Comment: There's a famous saying in computing -- There are two known difficult problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things and off-by-one errors

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you for helpful visualization and solution!

Answer (score 1):

arrays in javascript starts from `0`, your loop should start from `0` too

Comment: He's not using any array. Just incrementing `j` and `i`. You're almost right, it's an off-by-one error, but not for the reason in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use j<=cols. As you do the multiplication using the value j, j=0 will give you the result as 0.

Answer (score 1):

`for (j = 1; j <= cols; j++)` and `for (i = 2; i <= rows; i++)`

your loop is finishing early because of your condition `i < cols`. :)